# Syntax highlighting in bash while typing commands

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to highlight my input into the bash console while typing code?
For example, if I use bash keywords, those are highlighted in a specific color?

edit:
I'm particularly interested in solutions which make use of what bash already has to offer, like tweaking .bash_profile or similar.

Comment: "Is there a way"? Not built into bash. There's 3rd-party software you can use, but StackOverflow isn't in the business of recommending 3rd-party software (requests for such recommendations is specifically off-topic).

Comment: try `fish` shell. https://fishshell.com/

Answer (score -4):

You can use the syntax highlighting feature of vim/vi.

Open a file, for example open existing file called file.sh, enter

```
vi file.sh
```

Now press ESC key, type “: syntax on” i.e. type as follows

```
:syntax on
```

To turn it back off, press ESC key, type : syntax off

```
:syntax off
```

To make it permanent you can create a new .vimrc file in your home directory. Open the terminal and enter:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

There you can enter your various configurations. When done, you need to save the file and restart vim.

To be sure which vimrc is being used, you can ask inside of vim by typing:

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

Comment: The user was asking about _highlight my input into the bash console while typing code_, it's not about editing files.